# How can I prevent user access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a view that to access you must log in ,my users table I have a field called kind.
I am using gem devise

```
enum kind: {
    admin: 0,
    customer: 1
  }
```

add this in application_controller

```
def user_can_access(resource)
if current_user
   if resource.is_admin?
     root_path
   else
    sign_out current_user
    new_user_session_path
   end
end
```

end

user.rb

```
  def is_admin?
   self.admin?
  end
```

That is my attempt to solve it, but it is wrong since I want the user that I do not want to access the view to not login.
In my method, the user who does not have access logs in but then I log him out, which I think is wrong
How can I prevent client access?

note:I will only have a page for the administrator, the other users will not have a view to access.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the cancancan gem for authorization features or you can write yours then include a before action to check if the current_user is authorized before rendering the view.

e.g

```
class MyPage < ApplicationController
  before_action :is_authorized?
  
  def show_my_page
    @foo == bar
  end


  private
  
  def is_authorized?
    return true if current_user.kind == admin 
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are not allowed to access this page"
  end
end
```